# How do you use simple_form with nested ActiveModel objects (not ActiveRecord)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, simple-form-for

I am trying to use `simple_form` with `ActiveModel` objects to validate form data before I perform work using that data. This data won't be persisted to the database, hence not using `ActiveRecord`.

**Models:**

```
class SomeForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name, :items

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class SomeFormItem
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**Controller:**

```
def new
  @form = SomeForm.new
  @form.items = [SomeFormItem.new, SomeFormItem.new]
end
```

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for @form, url: some_destination_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= simple_fields_for :items do |i| %>
    <%= i.input :name, label: "Item Name" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I would expect to get 2 fields called "Item Name" one for each `SomeFormItem` added to `items`, however, I only get 1 and also it id not named with an array format that I would expect normally, e.g. `some_form[items][0][name]`.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here or do I need to do this manually?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare an id attribute for your nested item and assign a (integer) value to it before you render it in the form.